# Non parametric test for the three way anova

Tags: anova, nonparametric

Is there an alternative for the three way anova in the case that the assumptions of the three way anova are not met?
(So I am looking for a non-parametric test with three factors)

Comment: As a short cut, you could always rank the observations after an ascending sort, and input the ranks into 3-way ANOVA.  Sure, there are assumptions about doing this, but we have done it for publications before.

Comment: You can bootstrap ...